# Can I use a non-ARC build framework in a ARC build application?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, automatic-ref-counting

My project is created with ARC turned on, now I am using a third party framework which highly likely wasn't built with ARC. Will that any problem with that? I am now running into a crash happened somewhere in the framework but I got not much of details about the crash. So I am wondering if this because of the ARC mismatch.

Comment: something like the following-[__NSCFString stringWithPercentEscape]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79812e0
2012-03-09 13:22:12.348 app[6462:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString stringWithPercentEscape]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79812e0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine.

If your framework is a static or dynamic library:
ARC inserts release statements into your code at compile time, but if the framework is ready compiled this won't be a problem.

If you need to compile the framework yourself:
You can mark specific files as non-ARC in Xcode. There's a per file compiler flag.